# Get a single TIFF using multiple TIFFs and masks

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, scikit-image, rasterio, satellite-image

I'm working with satellite imagery (from Sentinel-2), in particular with cloud detection and cloud cleaning.

I got a batch of images of the same area, but in different periods:
[image]

[image]

[image]

From these images, you can see that the position of the clouds is always different.

I also have the mask for each image, where the black areas represent clouds:

[image]

[image]

[image]

These masks are not perfect, but this is not a problem.

What I want to do is to use the mask to cut all the white portions (so get the land and exclude the clouds), and then fill these cuts with a black portion of another image (fill the "*hole*" in the image with a part of another image without clouds).

Imagery is in TIFF format, while masks are in JPG format.

I'm using Python with libraries like Rasterio, numpy and scikit-image, so a Pythonic solution would be appreciated.

Comment: Still not a code writing service. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/46269102/18667225

Comment: @nick ["_We-are-not-a-code-writing-service comments. Are they the good, the bad, or the ugly?_"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/372166/11107541), [Note: Implementation effort is not a hard requirement for asking a question on SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260828/11107541).

Comment: Surely just a little extension to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/74701747/2836621

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Crop TIFF using JPG mask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74700266/crop-tiff-using-jpg-mask)